# Problem with JS displaying NaN when entire form table is not filled in

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm trying to make a grade calculator and I have run into some problems with my JS form table.

I'm trying to find a way so that if the user does not type in numbers for all 3 of the b, c, and d values it will still give me the user's class grade.

However, when the user is not typing in numbers for all 3 of the b, c, and d values, I'm getting the result of `NaN`. My program works, when there are numbers in all 3 of the b, c, and d values, but I also want it to work when there isn't.

*Note: I am new to both JS and HTML.*

Here's my code:

```js
function calcGrade() {
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  var c = 0;
  var d = 0;
  var e = 0;
  var f = 0;
  var g = 0;
  var h = 0;
  var z = 0;

  var cg = 0;
  var cg1 = 0;
  var cg2 = 0;
  var cg3 = 0;
  var cg4 = 0;
  var cg5 = 0;
  var cg6 = 0;
  var cg7 = 0;
  var cg8 = 0;

  //First Row
  var B1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").valueAsNumber);
  var C1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c1").valueAsNumber);
  var D1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("d1").valueAsNumber);

  //Second Row
  var B2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b2").valueAsNumber);
  var C2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c2").valueAsNumber);
  var D2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("d2").valueAsNumber);


  //Third Row
  var B3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b3").valueAsNumber);
  var C3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c3").valueAsNumber);
  var D3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("d3").valueAsNumber);

  //Fourth Row
  var B4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b4").valueAsNumber);
  var C4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c4").valueAsNumber);
  var D4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("d4").valueAsNumber);

  //Fifth Row
  var B5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b5").valueAsNumber);
  var C5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c5").valueAsNumber);
  var D5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("d5").valueAsNumber);


  //Sixth Row
  var B6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b6").valueAsNumber);
  var C6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c6").valueAsNumber);
  var D6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("d6").valueAsNumber);

  //Seventh Row
  var B7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b7").valueAsNumber);
  var C7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c7").valueAsNumber);
  var D7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("d7").valueAsNumber);


  //Eigth Row
  var B8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b8").valueAsNumber);
  var C8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c8").valueAsNumber);
  var D8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("d8").valueAsNumber);

  //Calculations
  a = (((B1) / (C1)) * (D1));
  b = (((B2) / (C2)) * (D2));
  c = (((B3) / (C3)) * (D3));
  d = (((B4) / (C4)) * (D4));
  e = (((B5) / (C5)) * (D5));
  f = (((B6) / (C6)) * (D6));
  g = (((B7) / (C7)) * (D7));
  h = (((B8) / (C8)) * (D8));

  z = parseFloat(D1) + parseFloat(D2) + parseFloat(D3) + parseFloat(D4) + parseFloat(D5) + parseFloat(D6) + parseFloat(D7) + parseFloat(D8);


  cg = ((((B1) / (C1)) * (D1)) + (((B2) / (C2)) * (D2)) + (((B3) / (C3)) * (D3)) + (((B4) / (C4)) * (D4)) + (((B5) / (C5)) * (D5)) + (((B6) / (C6)) * (D6)) + (((B7) / (C7)) * (D7)) + h) / (z);

  if (z > 100) {
    alert("Error, your weight percentage column is over 100, please make sure it is less than or equal to 100!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML = z;
    document.getElementById("classGrade").innerHTML = cg;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="classGradeCalc" action>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Grading Category</td>
        <td>Points Earned</td>
        <td>Max Poins</td>
        <td>Weight</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="20" id="a1" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="b1" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="c1" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="d1" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="20" id="a2" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="b2" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="c2" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="d2" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="20" id="a3" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="b3" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="c3" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="d3" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="20" id="a4" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="b4" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="c4" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="d4" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="20" id="a5" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="b5" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="c5" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="d5" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="20" id="a6" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="b6" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="c6" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="d6" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="20" id="a7" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="b7" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="c7" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="d7" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="20" id="a8" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="b8" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="c8" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" size="5" id="d8" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Calculate Grade" onclick="calcGrade()"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Class Grade</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input size="5" name="gca1"></td>
        <td><input size="5" name="gca2"></td>
        <p id="pointsEarned"></p>
        <p id="maxPoints"></p>
        <p id="weight"></p>
        <p id="classGrade"></p>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: using a `<form>` is a bad idea : any keyboard return will force a page reloading and clear all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As you know in HTML input every value is string, when you try to convert it in number and there is not any number (When you have not any value in input it will it's default value is "") value it returns NaN value (Not a Number);

To avoid this you can check if is NaN then don't do any mathematical operation with NaN;

Use Number.isNaN() to check .

But in this case I would recommend to mark three inputs as required fields, because there is not addition, here divsion and multiplication. There is not possible just use two values without any NaN issues .

Comment: So what would I do after I complete a Number.isNan() check? Do I assign the value a number if it is NaN? I'm really just trying to figure out if there is anyway to print out the class grade without all of the columns being filled in.

Comment: I guess you can, assign default value to this but you should take account two cases if it is  substraction or addition let it be 0 if it is multiplication  or division let it be 1.  Like this parseFloat(document.getElementById("b8").valueAsNumber) || 1 or you can check (Number.isNaN(B1) ? 1 : B1)

Answer (score 0):

## Problem:

This part of your code below is what's giving you the problem.

```js
  a = (((B1) / (C1)) * (D1));
  b = (((B2) / (C2)) * (D2));
  c = (((B3) / (C3)) * (D3));
  d = (((B4) / (C4)) * (D4));
  e = (((B5) / (C5)) * (D5));
  f = (((B6) / (C6)) * (D6));
  g = (((B7) / (C7)) * (D7));
  h = (((B8) / (C8)) * (D8));

  z = parseFloat(D1) + parseFloat(D2) + parseFloat(D3) + parseFloat(D4) + parseFloat(D5) + parseFloat(D6) + parseFloat(D7) + parseFloat(D8);


  cg = ((((B1) / (C1)) * (D1)) + (((B2) / (C2)) * (D2)) + (((B3) / (C3)) * (D3)) + (((B4) / (C4)) * (D4)) + (((B5) / (C5)) * (D5)) + (((B6) / (C6)) * (D6)) + (((B7) / (C7)) * (D7)) + h) / (z);
```

Here `(B/C) * D` this part is the problem because when no values are entered the equation becomes `(0/0) * 0` & in JS `0/0 = NaN` and after that doesn't matter which operations you perform the result will always end-up being `NaN`

Another situation that might not have encountered while testing is that if only C Value is not given, then the equation becomes: `(B/0) * D` in this situation, the answer will end-up being `Infinity`. Because in JS `anyNumberX / 0 = Infinity`

## Solution:

Now, the solutions to this issue is that you re-code your calculations such that Denominators don't end-up having the value 0.

To be true, the simplest & realistic solution would be to conditionally check that all the values are given & if not, then just show an alert to the user asking for all valid values to be inputted.

Comment: I put the extra rows in the table just in case the user needed those rows. So maybe I could find a way to delete the unneeded rows. I don't want the user to use all the rows if its not needed because it would mess up their class grade. That's why i assigned it as "0". I'll mess around and see what i can do.

Comment: What you can do in this case is have a `+` button which will dynamically add another row. This will be easier for you as well as the User. And I would recommend that you explore a bit about **HTML DATA Attribute**, this could help you in connecting the dynamically generated UI with JS & getting access to the Values easily.